# why does this code give me runtime error? C

Tags: c

I don't understand why it keeps giving runtime errors :/ What is wrong in there? How can I resolve this problem?
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int i=0, ch;
    char word[100];
    for(;(ch = getc(stdin)) != EOF;)
    {
        do{
            word[i] = ch;
            if(ch == 32) word[i] = '\0';
            i++;
        } while(ch != 32);

    }
    printf("%s", word);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please mention the error you are seeing.

Comment: Runtime error #stdin #stdout 0s 4524KB

Comment: Follow it through. What happens with the first character being, say,  `A`?

Comment: doesn't matter what I input, it gives me runtime error :/

Comment: Hint: `ch` never changes inside the inner loop

Comment: Read [*how to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @OrangeBike What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow just trying to practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this loop:

```
    do{
        word[i] = ch;
        if(ch == 32) word[i] = '\0';
        i++;
    } while(ch != 32);
```

The value of `ch` never changes, so you have an infinite loop.  You also as a result end up writing past the end of the buffer `word` because `i` is increasing without bound, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You don't need two loops here.  Just check for both EOF and a space.  Also, you should use the character constant `' '` for a space instead of its ASCII code.

```
for (i=0; ((ch = getc(stdin)) != EOF) && (ch != ' '); i++)
{
    word[i] = ch;
    if(ch == ' ') word[i] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    do{
        word[i] = ch;
        if(ch == 32) word[i] = '\0';
        i++;
    } while(ch != 32);
```

You're overflowing your buffer on the first key press. Which should point out the broader problem of a fixed size buffer with no range checking, in addition to this broken piece of code.

Comment: if he enters only a single character, followed by 32, then?

Comment: @hacker315 they will never find 32, because getch is in the outer loop.